# Xcode, C++ and SFML. Library issues

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, sfml

I am trying to compile a simpel code that will show me a window by using Xcode with my mac.
Everything seems to work and I get "Build Succeeded". But then nothing happens and I get the message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-audio.2.4.dylib
>
> Referenced
> from:
> /Users/zeeshanaslam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-frpvsmylufuctqaphblszdoivflt/Build/Products/Debug/test
>
> Reason: image not found

I am very new to programming, so please could any one help me with this problem.

My code is:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480),"TEST");
    
    while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event evnt;
        
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)){
            if(evnt.type == evnt.Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if its the code or Xcode is what causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run this code completely fine (OS X 10.11.6, Xcode 8.2.1). Here were my steps to getting it to run:

1. `brew install sfml` in the terminal.
2. Added `/usr/local/sfml/cellar/sfml/2.4.2/include` to my header search path in xcode.
3. In `/usr/local/sfml/cellar/sfml/2.4.2/lib`, I dragged the audio, graphics, network, system and window dylibs into xcode. This is sufficient for xcode to link (and run) your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and now I am a happy SFML/C++ user :)